# Get substing of a column in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a column with a long text, and i need to find an specific string inside of it.

for example:
the column contains this: "Hello mi number is C.C. 2313"

and i need to extract "C.C. 2313"

Im using an Oracle 11g Database.

Comment: Is there a pattern of your string, which you will be searching? have a look at [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm)

Comment: Yes the string will be always start with "C.C." or "c.c." or "cc"

Comment: 1. Will there always be a substring containing C.C. or c.c. or cc? If not, what is the desired result? 2. Will there always be exactly one such substring? 3. If there is exactly one such substring, what do you need extracted? Everything from that substring to the end of the input string? That is the case in your example, but is that the requirement in general?

Answer (score 1):

Variable separators are tricky in Oracle.  Here is one method:

```
select substr(col, length(regexp_substr(col, '.*(cc|[cC][.][cC][.]')) + 1)
```

Oh, the above removes the separator.  You want it, so that is easier:

```
select regexp_substr(col, 'cc|[cC][.][cC][.].*')
```

Comment: At least since Oracle 11.1, you can use the `match_parameter` argument to `regexp_substr` to simplify - use the `'i'` value for case insensitive matching.

Answer (score 0):

This should help

1. The below is sample of how you can make it work.
2. My suggestion, would be to have a trigger on the table, to insert the part of the string as a separate column in the table

`WITH data AS
        (SELECT 'Hello mi number is C.C. 2313' column_Value
        FROM dual
        UNION
        SELECT 'Hello mi number is c.c. 2414' column_Value
        FROM dual
        UNION
        SELECT 'Hello mi number is cc 2515' column_Value
        FROM dual
        )
    SELECT 1,
        SUBSTR(column_value, instr(column_value,'cc') + 2)
    FROM data
    WHERE column_value LIKE '%cc%'
    UNION
    SELECT 2,
        SUBSTR(column_value, instr(column_value,'c.c.',1) + 4)
    FROM data
    WHERE column_value LIKE '%c.c.%'
    UNION
    SELECT 3,
        SUBSTR(column_value, instr(column_value, 'C.C.') + 4)
    FROM data
    WHERE column_value LIKE '%C.C.%'
    ;`

Answer (score 0):

I put answer in case that length of column is variable (it's easier if it is fixed):

```
create table t10(
test varchar2 (30));

insert into t10 (test) values ('Hello mi number is C.C. 2313');

select  substr(test,instr(test, 'C.C.'),length(test))  from t10 ar;
```

You can also divide for all variation of C.C. cc C.c. c.c. with case when

Comment: Hint: In the SUBSTR function, if you do not specify the third argument, the substring will extend to the end of the input string. (In any case, the third argument shows how many characters to extract, not the position of the last character to extract, so "length(test)" is generally not the right value anyway.)